# Seeing what Linux kernel compile options where used

Tags: linux, kernel

Is it possible to tell what compile options a running Linux kernel has been built with?

I am particularly interested in those that impact on preemptive behavior, such as  CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY.

Thanks
Pete

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, indeed /boot is the place to look for config* files.